# Missing dependencies message after login

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, 19.10

After upgrade to 19.10, every time I log in, the following message appears and only after clicking *Cancel*, log in continues.

> System Monitor Extension
>
> Dependencies Missing
>
> Please install:
>
> libgtop, Network Manager and gir bindings
>
> on Ubuntu: gir1.2-gtop-2.0,gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
>
> ...

How to get rid of this message?

[image]

Comment: Have you try to do what it is recommended to do ? (`sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0`) If so, does it change anything ?

Comment: @dc37, yes, I tried, the thing is that gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 is not available for 19.10

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that in Ubuntu 19.10 the `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0` has been replaced by the package `gir1.2-nm-1.0` (see [this page](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/ubuntu-main-i386/gir1.2-nm-1.0_1.20.4-2ubuntu2_i386.deb.html))

Try to search this package by doing:

```
sudo apt-cache search -n gir1.2
```

if you find this package, you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-nm-1.0
```

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: Did not work, it results that that package was already installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure all dependencies in order:

`sudo apt-get install gnome`

Then:

`gnome-shell --replace &`

`reboot`

Comment: sudo apt-get install gnome: 19 upgraded, 152 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded. I am not sure about installing such amount of new packages.

Comment: did it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this elsewhere:

```
apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

I had to log out and back in for it to work.

Comment: Thanks but:
gir1.2-clutter-1.0 is already the newest version (1.26.2+dfsg-12).
gir1.2-gtop-2.0 is already the newest version (2.40.0-2).

Comment: did not work on Ubuntu 19.10 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

##### Outdated local copy of the extenstion

In my case, I had an old local copy of the extension that was outdated:

```
$ ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
```

So I removed it:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
```

In my case I already had the extension installed as an Ubuntu package as well, but it wouldn't hurt to make sure it's installed:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor
```

The changes should take effect the next time you log in.

##### Dependencies

If you've installed from the Ubuntu package (as I've recommended above), the dependencies should already be installed for you. If you've installed the extension manually, you can try installing these packages:

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0
```

As above, the changes should take effect the next time you log in.

##### Check the error logs

Run this command to check the gnome-shell error logs:

```
sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

For example, these are some of the logs I saw that helped me realize I had two copies of the extension installed (as described above):

```
Error: Requiring NMClient, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'NMClient' (any version) not found
System monitor applet init from /home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
System monitor applet enabling
Some code tried to set a deprecated GObject property.
0 _patchContainerClass/containerClass.prototype.child_set() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js":34:12]
1 _patchContainerClass/containerClass.prototype.add() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js":43:17]
2 _init() ["/home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/extension.js":200:27]
...
Extension system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com already installed in /home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.co>
```